# osx create-react-app not installing

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to install react using the terminal command:

> npm install -g create-react-app

But it doesn't seem to be working and I get the following output:

[create-react-app output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyVtD.jpg)

Does anyone know what might be the problem here?

Comment: Forgot to say, I have already installed the latest version of Node and npm and seemed to work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before you continue please take a [tour] and then read [ask]. Reading and understanding these would help your question to not get flagged. For your questions answer try using `sudo`. It looks like you don't have permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see in screenshot, you just need use this command as administrator `sudo npm install -g create-react-app`.

Comment: not a great idea, just means his node install is bad. I would recommend using nvm to install and manage node locally to user and w/o suid / perm issues.

Answer (score 1):

In case you stumbled here because of this error:

> -bash: create-react-app: command not found

Then you need to do this:

```
npx create-react-app yourApp
```

Essentially you need to prepend `create-react-app` with `npx`.